# Pod install private pods URI::InvalidURIError - bad URI(is not URI?)

Tags: ios, ruby, git, rubygems, cocoapods

I have a git repo on gitlab using a private pod along with other public pods, below is my Podfile

```
source 'git@gitlab.mycompany.com:cocoapods/cocoapodsspecs.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '6.0'

target "main-project-target" do
    ....
end
```

I have 2 macs both on 10.10 Yosemite, and I clone my project on gitlab, and do pod install to get the libraries.

The first one's configuration is below:

```
CocoaPods : 0.34.4
Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [x86_64-darwin13.3.0]
RubyGems : 2.1.9
Host : Mac OS X 10.10 (14A389)
Xcode : 6.1 (6A1052d) 
Git : git version 1.9.3 (Apple Git-50) 
Ruby lib dir : /Users/a-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p481/lib 
Repositories : my-project - git@gitlab.mycompany.com:cocoapods/cocoapodsspecs.git @4fff1c9692486e603edf643013f1136a762cdcdf
master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ c9acfa46c81ffa93063a56d342afa7c0de71c345
```

It can do pod install without any problems, all the libraries including my private pod is well installed.

My second mac is a new one, I cannot succeed in installing pod, in the beginning I thought it was the system default ruby's problem, so I installed ruby with homebrew, below is the configuration:

```
CocoaPods : 0.34.4
    Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p594 (2014-10-27 revision 48167) [x86_64-darwin14.0.0]
RubyGems : 2.4.2
    Host : Mac OS X 10.10 (14A389)
   Xcode : 6.1 (6A1052d)
     Git : git version 2.1.2
Ruby lib dir : /Users/a-user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.4/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 2a7c343fc975097c436c080765b736aefa5e2629
```

clearly cocoa pods did not find my private pod, and the error message is:

````
### Error

```
URI::InvalidURIError - bad URI(is not URI?):git@gitlab.mycompany.com:cocoapods/cocoapodsspecs.git
````

I also tried to install ruby 2.0.0 to get coherent with my old mac, but I got the same messages.

PS: I can clone my private git library without any problem.

I had searched a lot in Cocoapods issues on GitHub, like https://github.com/CocoaPods/Core/issues/82, but found nothing similar to my case.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fint out the solution, just add the private repo to Pods helps out:

```
pod repo add my-repo git@gitlab.mycompany.com:cocoapods/cocoapodsspecs.git
```

It really has nothing to do with invalid url, the error message is quite misleading. Hope that can help